# Why do different energy levels affect the probability amplitude of the wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

When you solve the Schrödinger equation for the classic particle in a box you get that $$\psi=\sqrt{ \frac{2}{l}} \sin{(\frac {n\pi x}l)}$$
where $x$ is the length from the leftmost point of the box, $l$ is the length of the box and $n$ is an integer where $$n=\sqrt{\frac{El^2}{\pi^2}}$$($E$ is equal to the energy in the quantum particle or whatever) and so the wave function clearly depends on the energy of the particle or the system right? So my question is:
why is that so? Why does the quantum wavefunction have to depend on the energy level of the particle or the quantum system? I mean what we're calculating through the wavefunction is the probability of a quantum particle being at a specific place between some certain potentials right? So how does the energy effect where an electron or any other quantum particle is? I had this idea that since the electron is in a superposition of every possible place it could be in, it interacts with its own energy level that's at another position but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Energy eigenstates are not physical states that you can actually put a particle in. They're mathematical fictions used to calculate things.

Answer (score 1):

By solving the TISE and wondering why its solutions depend on the energy, you are [begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question). The TISE reads $$\hat H\lvert\psi\rangle = E\lvert\psi\rangle$$ where $E$ is the energy eigenvalue, i.e. the energy of the system when it is in the state $\lvert\psi\rangle$. In other words, the $\psi$ that you have obtained above came from a process of looking for wavefunctions with specific energy levels, so of course the wavefunctions you'll find will depend on the energy level.

In general, the quantum wavefunction need not depend on the energy level, or even have a well defined energy for that matter. The solutions to the TISE are the set of quantum states that have well defined energies, and they form a complete basis, so any state can be expressed as a linear combination (superposition) of them. The main reason why it is useful to express states in this basis is because the time evolution is just a phase factor in this basis.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}$
The time-independent Schrödinger Equation written in Dirac notation is often expressed as $$ H\ket{\psi_n} = E_n\ket{\psi_n}, $$ which is know in Mathematics as an eigenvalue equation. It is "more proper" to see the dependencies of the energy eigen-value as having dependencies on $n$, instead of the $n$ in the $n$-th eigenstate/eigenfunction or eigen-energy as being a function of energy. However, it is indeed possible to "invert" the function as you have done to make $n$ the subject, improperly eluding to the probability amplitude being a function a the energy levels.

Comment: thanx for the answer...but why does the positional probability of a quantum particle depend on its energy level...I mean logically it really shouldn't matter. All that should matter is the potentials of the system

Comment: Once again, consider the $\langle x | \psi_n \rangle$ as function of $n$, not $E$.

Comment: I don't know what that notation means( btw it would be great if you could explain it to me but I do know the bra ket notation(I just don't know what the real life meaning of it is))...Anyway even if I DID think of it as a function of n since E is a function of n I'd be thinking of it as a function of E, indirectly

Answer (score 0):

Go to a more [complicated system](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydwf.html), the [orbitals of the hydrogen](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html) atom which give the solution for the possible locations in (x,y,z) of an electron trapped around a proton.

[image: hydrorb]

1,2,3 is the $n$ , the quantum number connected with the energy level, and there is a difference in space for the probability of the electron.

Why?

That's what the solution gives.